# PHP Twig: access current template variable from within macro without passing?

Tags: php, twig, silex

Is it possible to access the current template's variables from within a macro without passing the variable to the macro directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible to pass all context variables to a macro:

```
{{ macro(_context) }}
```

`_context` is a [special variable](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#global-variables), which contains all currently defined variables (by name => value).