# How can I access template variable in TWIG macro?

Tags: variables, macros, twig

I'm not able to access template variable in TWIG macro.

Here is a simplified example:

```
{% set myname = "Ligio" %}
{{ _self.pagedurl(1) }}

{% macro pagedurl(page) %}
    Hi {{ _self.myname }}! This is Page Num {{ page }}
{% endmacro %}
```

How can I access the variable **myname** without passing it to the macro?

Comment: Did you try a simple `{{ myname }}`?

Comment: with {{ myname }} I'm not in the scope of the variable... 
It's not working!

Answer (score 25):

You can not.

As stated in the documentation:

> As PHP functions, macros don't have access to the current template
>   variables.

Your only solution is to pass the parameter to the `macro`:

```
{% import _self as flow %}
{{ flow.pagedurl(1, "Ligio") }}

{% macro pagedurl(page, myname) %}
    Hi {{ myname }}! This is Page Num {{ page }}
{% endmacro %}
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

You may have noticed in my example, I call `{% import _self as flow %}`.
This is something you **MUST** do:

> When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it,
>   you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input()
>   instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a
>   side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in
>   Twig 2.x.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

Comment: One solution that can "hack" your "globals" is to build a twig var (or use _context) as an array of your important variables and then pass this single twig var as the last argument to any macro you use.  --------- When within the scope of your macro you can then access this final argument via the varargs property.   for example:  {% set MyGlobals = varargs[0] %}

Comment: It seems with Twig 3.x we don't need to import _self and you should not.

Comment: The documentation justification seems ridiculous. PHP functions may have access to global variables, and PHP methods have access to class members. They could just stay it's by design instead of trying to blame it on PHP.

Comment: Quoting Symfony docs, it's about the Twig version (https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html): "Auto-import is only available as of Twig 2.11. For older versions, import macros using the special _self variable for the template name:"

Answer (score 13):

If you need to pass more than one global variable into the macro, you might find the `_context` variable useful:

```
{% macro mymacro(globalvars) %}
    Value of the global variable pi is {{ globalvars.pi }}
{% endmacro %}

{% set pi = 3.14159 %}
{{ _self.mymacro(_context) }}
```

Ref: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7611419/523100) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20372991/523100) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a global variable and access it anywhere in the template

```
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem('path/to/templates');
$twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addGlobal('V_Name', 'V_Value');
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the best solution when working with Timber/Twig/WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use a template var in macros without passing it around every time (symfony)

Created a Twig AppExtension Service with private $var and getter/setter

```
  class AppExtension extends AbstractExtension
  {
        private $var;
    
        public function getFunctions(): array
        {
            return [
                new TwigFunction('setVar', [$this, 'setVar']),
                new TwigFunction('getVar', [$this, 'getVar'])
            ];
        }
    
        public function setVar(Article $article)
        {
            $this->var = $article;
        }

        public function getVar()
        {
            return $this->var;
        }
  }
```

Set your var inside your template.html.twig

```
{% from '.../macros.html.twig' import showTitle, showImage %}
{{ setVar(article) }}

{{ showTitle('foo') }}
{{ showImage('bar') }}
```

You can now use getVar() to access article in macros.html.twig

```
{% macro showTitle(className) %}
    <p class="{{ className }}">{{ getVar().title }}</p>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro showImage(className) %}
    <img class="{{ className }}" src="{{ getVar().image }}"/>
{% endmacro %}
```

NB: may not be the most efficient solution, but works great

Comment: You could remove the `setVat` part by just settings the `needs_context` option to true though