# How do I access the _context variable within a macro in TWIG?

Tags: php, macros, twig

I'm trying to access one of my twig variables in a macro.   I know I can't do this directly.

> as with PHP functions, macros don't have access to the current template variables

but the same page state:

> You can pass the whole context as an argument by using the special _context variable.

What's the syntax for passing _context to the macro, and for accessing it within the macro?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider the following example:

1) Create a variable in the current context

```
{% set x = 42 %}
```

2) Declare a macro that takes an object as parameter

```
{% macro test(variables) %}
   variable x = {{ variables.x | default('undefined') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

3) Call your macro, with the special `_context` object

```
{{ _self.test(_context) }}
```

This will display:

> variable x = 42

Comment: Anyone know if there is a performance penalty to passing in the whole context like that?  If I have a lot of large objects in the context, will it copy everything if I pass in the context like that?   Does the macro make its own copy of context, or does it work directly on the global _context variables?

Comment: `$context` is just an array that is passed (by copy) to your macro. If it contains objects, only its references are copied, so that's ok. You can look how the Twig code is converted to php by looking at the right pane of [this fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/xqj9pj).

Comment: @Alain Can you please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48035901/how-to-evaluate-twig-expression

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the context variable should *not* be named `_context` (`context`, or `variables`, as in the example above, are fine.)

Answer (score 1):

**You could also use the varargs property of the macro (h*andy if you don't want to stipulate a parameter in the macro*):**

1. I assume you have a few twig vars stipulated in your template.

   ```
      {%set bodyType = "skinny" %}
   ```
2. With any twig macro you pass in the **_context** as **the final argument**.

   ```
     {{ _self.MyAmazaingMacroThatDoesEverything("french fries",_context)
   ```
3. in the macro:

   ```
     {% macro MyAmazaingMacroThatDoesEverything(healthyFood) %}
          variable yourTwigPageVar = {{ varargs[0].bodyType | default('undefined') }}

          <h1>I like {{healthyFood}}, eating them that makes me {{yourTwigPageVar}}</h2>


     {% endmacro %}
   ```