# How to evaluate twig expression

Tags: twig

I've bend over backwards to solve this one, but no luck yet.

```
{% for field in fields %}
    {{dump(form.children.~(field.label)~.vars.value)}}
{% endfor %}
```

U see the above code in twig? How do I get twig to evaluate `(field.label)` first and then evaluate the rest of the expression(`(form.children.Age.vars.value)`). For now it throws the twig syntax error

```
Expected name or number.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
{% for field in fields %}
    {{ dump(form.children[field.label].vars.value) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Wouter for the style :) I hate the mobile app 