# Render a php variable inside a twig template

Tags: php, function, variables, twig, render

I have a php variable like this:

```
$text = "Hello {{ name }}!";
```

I call $twig->render with the variable "name" set to John Doe.

In my twig template I use an own funktion to display the text:

```
{% block test %}
  My name is: {{name}}
  <h3>
    {{ d("text") }}
  </h3>
{% endblock %}
```

I just put the {{name}} inside my template to demonstrate the result. The Twig_Function "d" just returns $text, so that i get:

```
My name is: John Doe
<h3>
  Hello {{ name }}!
</h3>
```

My expected result should be:

```
My name is: John Doe
<h3>
  Hello John Doe!
</h3>
```

Both should be rendered: my normal {{name}} and my {{name}} placed in $text. So basicly I want the render engine from twig to render my variable $text after it was placed into the template. Is that possible?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [template_from_string()](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html)

Comment: @PatrickQ: you made my day... this was the right hint!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to  @Patrick Q... I just had to put an include() around template_from_string() and it works as expected:

```
{% block test %}
  My name is: {{name}}
  <h3>
    {{ include(template_from_string(d("text"))) }}
  </h3>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's an explanation: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/template_from_string.html

Comment: BTW: knows someone a way to bring this `include(template_from_string(d("text")))` into one function like `myfunction("text")` which does the same?

Comment: Found the solution for my question above: macros! The way using the (global) template variables inside the macro is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107760/how-can-i-access-template-variable-in-twig-macro